# Errors when using fetch --no-history chromium

Tags: chromium, gclient

I have this error when I use `fetch --no-history chromium`

```
No downloadable toolchain found. In order to use your locally installed version of Visual Studio to build Chrome please set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0.
For details search for DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN in the instructions at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/windows_build_instructions.md


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 589, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 585, in main
    return commands[sys.argv[1]](*sys.argv[2:])
  File "src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 531, in Update
    subprocess.check_call(get_toolchain_args)
  File "C:\workspace\depot_tools\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_26_bin\python3\bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\workspace\\depot_tools\\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_26_bin\\python3\\bin\\python3.exe', 'C:\\chromium\\src\\third_party\\depot_tools\\win_toolchain\\get_toolchain_if_necessary.py', '--output-json', 'C:\\chromium\\src\\build\\win_toolchain.json', '27370823e7', '--force']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I try `set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0` but running `gclient sync` to try to build again, but I get the same error.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2022 installed? You need a supported version of Visual Studio installed too.